# PDFKit not showing uploaded paperclip images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to generate PDF in rails but when I am trying to show uploaded image it will not displaying in the PDF I don't know what I am missing here? Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths for the images

from: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit

> Resources aren't included in the PDF: Images, CSS, or JavaScript does
>   not seem to be downloading correctly in the PDF. This is due to the
>   fact that wkhtmltopdf does not know where to find those files. Make
>   sure you are using absolute paths (start with forward slash) to your
>   resources. If you are using PDFKit to generate PDFs from a raw HTML
>   source make sure you use complete paths (either file paths or urls
>   including the domain). In restrictive server environments the root_url
>   configuration may be what you are looking for change your asset host.

Comment: Thanks it was due to the path issue. I passed /public with the path I was getting from my db and it works.